# Can somebody please explain what are these variables doing here?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, matching

I have this algorithm:

[image]

I understand overall what's happening here, we're shrinking the blossoms (odd cycles) to end up with a bipartite matching problem, and then opening them again to get a maximum matching in this graph. But I don't understand it algorithmically, like what do the variable considered and label represent. Can somebody please clarify that?

**Edit** This is taken from chapter 10 of 'Combinatorial Optimization: Algorithms and Complexity' book by Papadimitriou and Stieglitz.

Comment: Presumably, this excerpt is accompanied by just such an explanation.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, I have read the full chapter, but as I said, it tells the idea of what the algorithm does, but not how it does, precisely.

Comment: @D.W. edited it.